# What is the least noticable way to re-stream a video to Twitch?

Tags: video, streaming, setup

I have a local video file from a past Twitch stream (which I failed to archive), broadcast and recorded through OBS. My goal is to re-stream it to Twitch so that it feels as close as reasonably possible to a normal archived stream, in terms of quality, aspect ratio, position, sound, etc. The OBS Video Source Plugin has been recommended for this task. The original recorded file was in .flv format. I have since converted to .mp4, and cut a bit from the beginning with VideoPad Video Editor (I still have the original .flv file).

1) Will the outcome look and sound just as authentic using the converted and cut video file, assuming said file plays just as well on my local machine, or is it better to re-stream the original and cut it again using the Twitch highlight function?

2) What Video Source Settings should I use when adding the video file as a source via the plugin? Should the height and width always match the recorded video settings (pre-downscale, according to my understanding)? Is it better to select to stretch the image, which presumably overrides the entered height and width? What about "Deinterlacing" and "Apply Video Filters"?

3) Finally, in the Video Source Settings, what is the default volume (which is the full 100), the volume at which OBS normally streams, or should this be adjusted?

Answer (score 1):

You should try [FFsplit](http://www.ffsplit.com/), is easy to use and free. With proper settings you should loose few or no data at all.

1. Setup the encoder to match the quality (bitrate and aspect ratio) of the original file.
2. Add a new layer of window capturing, and adjust width, height and origin (x,y) to capture only the region of the video
3. Setup hotkeys on ffsplit so you can start the streaming when the video player is on focus

Start your stream first then play you video.

Find a quick-start guide here on [twitch.tv help](http://help.twitch.tv/customer/portal/articles/1279750-ffsplit-broadcasting), althoug this an old document, the new version of ffplist has few, but nice changes